Problem when trying run all the norm command and face : No such file or directory
System: Ubuntu 20.04
no such lsb modules
Edit: Ubuntu Desktop
After updating my main pc from 18.04 to 20.04. I have faced binutils could not upgrade problem. ubuntu 20.04 fix binutils
reliable(install:2.24.2 but 2.39 has been installed)
Have to fix it because it has broken my apt and dpkg system.

then i tried to use apt install --fix-broken still not work. (error: binutils)
apt --fix-broken install not working

Use dpkg --force-overwrite still not work.
How to recreate /var/lib/dpkg/status?


Then I got the big mistake: all the norm command such as sudo, su, vi, apt...etc not work. it said no such file and directory. at the same time my pc could not open the file system and all basic files. even the pc could not be opened. What am I missing here? anyway is there anyway to save my pc and save my datas on my hardware. thanx.

Your details make little sense to me, one package you mention is binutils where 20.04 uses 2.34-6ubuntu1.9 and 22.04 uses 2.38-4ubuntu2.6 BUT you mention 2.39 which doesn't match 20.04 or 22.04??? which is likely your issue.  You've polluted your system with other packages OR your details are incorrect (as details don't match 18.04, 20.04 or 22.04)..  If you want to backup your system, I'll suggest booting live media and backup from there (it's what I'd do), or non-destructively re-install..  You didn't mention if Server or Desktop (options differ for those two)

Ubuntu 22.10 (along with all flavors) is End-of-Life and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu.  https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/07/27/ubuntu-22-10-kinetic-kudu-end-of-life-reached-on-july-20-2023/   https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades  I looked up binutils, and 2.39-3ubuntu1 matches 22.10 which is EOL

I use the ubuntu desktop. not server.
